# How to obtain html5 file API functionality with browser dragged image

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fileapi

Like [google images](http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=ii), I'd like to obtain the functionality of **drag and drop images of html pages already loaded in browser**. 
I know there are some scripts that implement htm5 file API, but no one of this recognize in-browser images.
How to get it?

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole [tutorial on html5rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/) about how to do file drag and drop.

Comment: It doesn't explain how to obtain the functionality that i need.